# filter text from list view in an edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a list view and above that one edit text. In edit text, data is searched from the list view and show in edit text. In the list view some data are two words. For example, list view contains "car", "red car", "blue car" . Now if I type c in edit text, it shows only car, not the other two. How can I search all the above three, when c is typed. Here is my code...

```
 @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,        int count) {
            wordlength = ed.getText().length();
            editsort.clear();
            for(int i=0;i<word.length;i++){
                if(wordlength<=word[i].length()){
                    if(ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) word[i].subSequence(0, wordlength))){
                    editsort.add(word[i]);

                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `word` is the array of strings which you want to search in:

```
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          String searchFor = ed.getText().toString();
          editsort.clear();
          for( String whole : word ){
               for( String part : whole.split( " " ) ) {
                  if( part.startsWith( searchFor ) );
                    editsort.add( whole );
               }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you for replying.. I tried like you said. Now it is showing all the string which contains the letter. for example if I type c now, it is filtering all the data containing c. Then if I type ca it shows all the strings containing ca..But in my case,if ca is type ca, it should show data having first two letters car and the data which contains ca after the space like in "blue car". It shouldnt show if the letters will present in middle of a word. Hope I have explained it clearly.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. Could you tell me how to search the list based on the letters typed in the edittext? What is editsort here?